# why does gcc have to recognize int64 as long int?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

This is how LWT_ELEMID defined in liblwgeom_topo.h:

```
typedef int64_t LWT_INT64;
typedef LWT_INT64 LWT_ELEMID;
```

I include this .h file and define some argument in LWT_ELEMID type.

But it always warns me like this:
/home/user/xxx.c:880:36: warning: format '%lld' expects argument of type 'long long int', but argument 3 has type 'LWT_ELEMID' {aka 'const long int'} [-Wformat=]

or like this:
/home/user/xxx.c:3034:19: note: expected 'LWT_ELEMID *' {aka 'long int *'} but argument is of type 'lint64 *' {aka 'long long int *'}

my environment:

Thread model: posix

gcc version: 8.3.0 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1)

Target: x86_64-linux-gnu

Comment: You are supposed to use the macros in `<inttypes.h>` to construct the printf/scanf format specifiers for the types in `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: Maybe you should look at it from the other end. You seem to assume that `int64_t` is `long long int`. Why? You should not rely on details of one platform to be valid on another platform.

Answer (score 3):

For strange reasons, gcc for Linux went with making `long` 64 bits (even though `long long` has been available forever), thereby breaking backwards compatibility with 32 bit systems. So you have to use `%ld`, or better yet, avoid this whole `long` debacle and use the portable `PRIi64` conversion specifier from inttypes.h.

Example:

```c
#include <inttypes.h> // includes stdint.h internally
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  typedef int64_t LWT_INT64;
  typedef LWT_INT64 LWT_ELEMID;
  LWT_ELEMID x = 123;

  printf("%"PRIi64 "\n", x); // PRIi64 is a string literal, hence this syntax
}
```

Comment: On 64 bit Unixes, `long int` was always 64-bit. This predates both C99 and Linux.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I guess there was never any 16 bit Unix? In the Windows world, it probably inherited the need of making `long` 32 bits from MS DOS which had 16 bit `int`.

Comment: (Some flavors of MC68k did have 16 bit support however.)

Comment: The original Unix ("Unics") for PDP-7 was 18-bit. Unix for PDP-11 was 16-bit.

Comment: On the strange reasons: https://unix.org/version2/whatsnew/login_64bit.html, https://unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html

Comment: The rule on Linux has always (since the first 64-bit Linux architecture - DEC Alpha) been that `long int` is the same size as the pointer types (which are all the same size).

Comment: `long long` was originally a "common extension", not standard until C99.

Comment: A lot of early 16-bit Unix code tended to assume that `int` and pointer types were the same size (except on systems with a wider than 16-bit address space). That carried over into early 32-bit Unix code, but had to be dropped for 64-bit Unix code for efficiency reasons.

Comment: hmmm... in 64bit architectures `int` is 32bit, `long` is 64 bit, and `long long` is 128 bit.  To my knowledge this at least in Linux/BSD 64 bit systems.  It's possible that, for efficiency reasons, in systems that cannot use 128 bit integers, `long long` is also 64bit.  But I'm not aware of any.

Comment: @LuisColorado do you mean `sizeof(long long)` returns 16 on your Linux/BSD? Are you sure? 
I think you got confused and thought about `long double`

Comment: I'm not, but I can check.. Sorry, I was wrong, `long long` is 8 bytes. :) let me check on FreeBSD/clang...  equal... not 16 but 8.  I'm not confused, the thing is that normally I don't use `long long` at all at work.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is the underlying data model of your target platform.

What you are seeing is the `LP64` data model (`long` (as opposed to *long long*) and `pointer` are 64bit), which according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) is used by

> Most Unix and Unix-like systems, e.g., Solaris, Linux, BSD, macOS. Windows when using Cygwin; z/OS

whereas the `LLP64` data model (`long long` (as opposed to ordinary *long*) and `pointer` are 64bit) is (according to the same source) prevalent on

> Microsoft Windows (x86-64 and IA-64) using Visual C++; and MinGW

since `int64_t` are (by definition) always 64bit integers, and in the `LP64` model `long int` are also 64bit integers, the two types are the same.

Comment: Don't forget the `_t` in `int64_t`!